# Python 3.5.1 Input + position of caret/cursor

Tags: python, input, caret

I am at the start of learning coding, am starting with Pycharm 5.0.2 and Python 3.5.1.

Even so, I am a bit embarrassed about asking this question, it feels like it should be obvious.

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
```

How do I ensure that focus is on the input field when I run it?

Put another way, when I run it, how do I make so that all the user needs to do is type their name and press Enter, that they do not need to use the mouse to position the cursor in the right place.

Comment: You need do nothing. Most of your users won't be running the script in PyCharm, but in a terminal window. You can't move the cursor in a terminal window without the program moving it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Simple user I/O, like `input()` and `print()`, use text terminals (the exact details vary depending on which platform you are on).

Although the user may be running a graphical desktop, a terminal window is used by the Python runtime.  On Microsoft Windows that is called a console, on operating systems like Linux that is a terminal emulator like xterm.

These terminal windows act like a typewriter, in that (normally) the cursor is advanced automatically when a `print()` is done, or the prompt specified by `input()`.

You can see the effect of this, notice that you placed a space after the `?` in your prompt `"What is your name? "`.  If you had not done that then the cursor would be hard up against the `?`.

It is possible to control the cursor using packages like `curses`, but with straightforward text I/O there is no need.  Usually if that type of control is required then a full GUI package would be used like Tk or PyQt.

Comment: Let me give another example.

"nameSelf = input("What is your name? ")
print (nameSelf)

nameFriend = input("What is the name of your friend? ")
print (nameFriend)"

If I run this code, I get this output:

"What is your name? Penny
Penny
What is the name of your friend? "

The caret at the beginning of the last line.  In other words, when the second call for Input is processed, the caret appears ahead of the text question, rather than after it.

Comment: @Polik:  it works fine for me, and there is no carat `^` anywhere.  How are you running your program?  It could be a side-effect of PyCharm if you are using that.  I suggest you test it as your users will run it.   One possibility is that your environment is doing something strange with stderr.  `input()` prompt is written to stderr, `print()` is written to stdout.

Comment: Dang....caret has more than one meaning, I now realise.

I meant caret as in a text insertion point (which is probably a safer way to describe it.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on PyCharm,
There is 'soft wrap' and ' scroll to end' options to the left of your terminal.
Select 'scroll to end'.